# How can i raising error while python coverage test on azure devops pipeline?

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure-devops, pipeline, coverage.py

My test code have some fails.

but pipeline is ignore error and run successful.

[image]

How can i raise error?

azure-pipelines.yml

```
...
- script: |
    pipenv run coverage run --rcfile=coverage_config --source='.' manage.py test --keepdb
    pipenv run coverage xml
  displayName: 'Run tests'
  env:
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID)
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $(AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
    FLANB_DEBUG: 'True'

- task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@1
  inputs:
    codeCoverageTool: Cobertura
    summaryFileLocation: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/coverage.xml'
    reportDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/htmlcov'

...
```

Comment: Can you share your pipeline configuration?

Comment: Try to add `failOnStderr: true`

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk Let me try.

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk `failonstderr` got me always failed.

Answer (score 0):

> How can i raising error while python coverage test on azure devops pipeline?

This seems to be a known issue when we run the test using the command line/powershell/bash.

[Publishing test results with failed tests does not fail the build](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/1268)

Now, there is a `failTaskOnFailedTests` param for the Publish Test Results task:

```
- task: PublishTestResults@2
  inputs:
    testRunner: VSTest
    testResultsFiles: '**/*.trx'
    failTaskOnFailedTests: true
```

You could try to use the task `Publish Test Results` with param `failTaskOnFailedTests: true` instead of `PublishCodeCoverageResults` to resolve this issue.

Please check [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/publish-test-results?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#yaml-snippet) for some more details:

> To publish test results for Python using YAML, see [Python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/python?view=azure-devops) in the
> Ecosystems section of these topics, which also includes examples for
> other languages.

Hope this helps.